# Java Telegram API download all documents from one message

Tags: java, download, telegram, telegram-bot

Good afternoon, I ran into a problem:
Several files are sent to the chat bot in one message, how do I upload them all if the method is **GetMessage().getDocument()** returns only the first document.

I understand that you need something like:
**List list = update.getMessage().get Documents();**
but there is no such thing in the API.

Help.

I searched for various methods in the documentation, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Even if you send multiple files at once they all arrive in separate messages.

You can check it by calling this web api with your bot api key:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<apikey>/getUpdates
```

All documents are in different messages and that's exactly what you get in the Java api.

Comment: @РоманДенисов I added something to the answer. Maybe it helps a bit to understand.